# After enabling SSL icon font doesn't display correctly if http version of the website is called

Tags: css, wordpress, .htaccess, ssl, fonts

Here I have an icon font defined in CSS

```
.social li a.facebook:before { font-family: 'icomoon'; content: "\f09a"; }
```

Now if I call http://www.somewebsite.com instead of the icon a rectangle with the content `F09A` is displayed. In the sourcecode (Ctrl + U) the css is included like that

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='font-css' href='http://www.somewebsite.com/wp-content/themes/sometheme/css/iconfont.css?ver=4.3.6' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

In this css the font are included relatively

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'icomoon';
    src:url('../fonts/icomoon.eot?-m6u1i9');
    src:url('../fonts/icomoon.eot?#iefix-m6u1i9') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('../fonts/icomoon.woff') format('woff'),
        url('../fonts/icomoon.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('../fonts/icomoon.svg?-m6u1i9#icomoon') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

The site URL of Wordpress is set to https. If I click on the http stylesheet link in the inspector I get redirected to the https version of the css. In Chrome I get the following after calling the http version of the website:

> Font from origin 'https://www.somewebsite.com' has been blocked from
>   loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://somewebsite.com' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

It seems that there are two differences:

- http vs https
- www vs without www

Calling the https version of the website works fine. Here the font is displayed correctly.

Is there a way to have a http and a https version running of the same site? Or do I have to start forcing https via `.htaccess`?

Some side notes:

- Calling https://somewebsite.com leads to an unsecure connection warning
- Calling www.somewebsite.com redirects to https//www.somewebsite.com

Is the certificate only valid for www.somewebsite.com?

**Edit:**

Now I use a redirection at the domain level.

http://somewebsite.com is now redirecting to https://www.somewebsite.com
http://www.somewebsite.com is redirecting to https://www.somewebsite.com

Seems to work for the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, httpd.conf `<VirualHost>` entries allow you to run both https://www.example.com (on port 443) and http://www.example.com (on port 80).  You can even point them at the same physical disk locations (probably not the best idea).

You'll want to either supply "www" always or never. (ie. redirect to "www.yoursite.com" if www was not sent. Otherwise things like this will keep popping up.

In HTML/CSS you can specify "//somefile.example" to indicate you are making an absolute path reference but want to keep the same scheme that was used.

You can check your certificate to see what it is valid for in linux via:

```
openssl x509 -noout -in /yourcertfile -subject -issuer -dates
```

You want to make sure the `CN=` (Common Name) matches the hostname of your web server including any subdomains (ie. "www")

Comment: There are multiple ways of redirecting: `.htaccess`, domain provider configuration, ... Does it matter which one?

Answer (score 1):

You can't mix http and https content. You need to send everything with https and to use resources from another domain you need to set the header to allow access.

[See CORS](http://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html)

You can use this on the origin server in .htaccess.

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.somedomain.com
```

The cert seems only valid for www. So you need to always use www with https. `www.example.com` and `example.com` are 2 different domains. www is a subdomain.

Comment: Never `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` unless it's just to test something quickly.  This opens you up for [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)) vulnerabilities.

Comment: @GraemeWicksted He can either use that or the domain specifically. But if needs to use assets from another domain he will have to do that. Directly from w3 https://www.w3.org/wiki/CORS_Enabled

Comment: It would be interesting to see, where the mix of http and https does come from.

Comment: @PanamaJack You are correct.  Thank you for adjusting your example to indicate a specific domain to allow CORS.